# Get the actual Count of PDF Pages - Aspose SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, aspose

**Status:**

i used 'Aspose SDK - C# PDF Version' to Print out a document which has 3 pages.
i have created the instance object _pdfDocument to access details of the document, including the count of pages.

**what i am trying to do:**

give every page a footer with number of page and the count of all pages.

**problem is:**

when i print the document, i got 3 pages. while when i debug the code, it shows the count of  pages 2.

*code below.*

```
public class printingClass
{

 protected ICustomerService _customerService;
 private Document _pdfDocument;
 private Page _activePage;

 // ctor 
 public printingClass(ICustomerService customerService) {
      _pdfDocument = new Document();
      _customerService = customerService;
  }


  public void Print(string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF", string content)                                                               
  {
    
    AddPage(content);
    CountandFooter();

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    _pdfDocument.Save(ms);
     PrintPDF(ms, printerName);
  }

  private void AddPage(string content)
  {
        var Customers = _customerService.GetAllCustomers();

        _activePage = _pdfDocument.Pages.Add();
        _activePage.SetPageSize(597.6, 842.4);
        _activePage.PageInfo.Margin = new MarginInfo(30, 20,25,30);    
         
       var table = new Table
        {
            ColumnWidths = columnWidths,
            ColumnAdjustment = ColumnAdjustment.AutoFitToWindow,
            DefaultCellPadding = new MarginInfo(4.5, 2, 4.5, 2),
            Margin = { Top = 5, Bottom = 5 },
        };

        foreach (var Customer in Customers)
        {
            row = table.Rows.Add();
            row.FixedRowHeight = 35f;
            row.Cells.Add($"{Customer.Name}");
            row.Cells.Add($"{Customer.Mobile}");
            cell = row.Cells.Add("");

            cell.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

            row.Cells.Add($"{Customer.Mail}");
        }
        _activePage.Paragraphs.Add(table);
  } 
 
  private void CountandFooter()
  {
        var stamp = new PageNumberStamp()
        {
            Format = "dummy text, page: #",
            StartingNumber = 1,
            TopMargin = 10,
            RightMargin = 25,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        };

        stamp.TextState.FontSize = 8.0F;

        // in debug mode _pdfDocument.Pages.Count = 2, but actually should be 3
        foreach (Page page in _pdfDocument.Pages)
        {
            page.AddStamp(stamp);
        }


        
        if (_pdfDocument.Pages.Count > 1)
        {
            var textStamp = new TextStamp("see next page")
            {
                //Format = "see next page",
                //StartingNumber = 1,
                Value = "see next page",
                BottomMargin = 10,
                RightMargin = 25,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            };
            textStamp.TextState.FontSize = 8.0F;
            foreach (Page page in _pdfDocument.Pages)
            {
                if (page.Number < _pdfDocument.Pages.Count)
                    page.AddStamp(textStamp);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "_it shows the count of pages 2._" What is "_it_"? What exactly shows the count of pages being 2? When the PDF document referred to by `_pdfDocument` contains 3 pages, then the value of `_pdfDocument.Pages.Count` should be 3. If not, check if there is a newer version of Aspose SDK available. If you are already using the most current Aspose SDK version while observing your issue, then create a minimal and complete code example (self-contained and compilable) and file a bug report with the Aspose SDK team...

Comment: Hi. it refers to the count of pages in the instance object_pdfDocument. i can't update the sdk. it is legecy app and i have no permisson to do that even. Yes the count shoud be 3 but isn't. the funny thing when i explore the object _pdfDocument  in visual studio, i see the count is 3 but program run it write in console 2!

Comment: I don't know for certain, of course, but if you ask me, i would bet on you making a mistake in your code (or debugging) when outputting the page count to the console (i.e., the PDF document actually having only two pages yet at the time of console output of the page count, with the 3rd page added to the document after outputting the page count). But then again, i am not an Aspose SDK user, so i am entirely blind-guessing and therefore might be betting on the wrong horse here...

Comment: Please try to use Document.ProcessParagraphs() method before getting the count of the pages and processing the PDF further. This method will save and update the collections in the document object and you will get correct count of the pages. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi @AsadAli thanks, that was realy helpfull. _pdfDocument.ProcessParagraphs() works now and i get the actual count of the pages. you can mark this comment as an Answer.

Comment: @AsadAli another question, i have a page which includes text, table and signature. how to break the page to another when the text gets bigger, so that the text in first page and the table and signature in the second page.

Comment: It would be difficult to determine when API is adding a new page automatically due to content exceeding one page boundaries. However, you can tell the API to always render the Table on a new page by specifying table.IsInNewPage property.